# Trouble with GeoJSON in HTTP GET Request

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson, format

I using a Vector Layer with the HTTP protocol to request GeoJSON from my web server, and am trying to get this GeoJSON to display on my map. The GET request appears to be working correctly, as I can see the example JSON I requested in Firebug. However, I am getting an error telling me that "this.format is null     Openlayers.js (line 1186)". Unfortunately, the OpenLayers.js file is essentially unreadable so I am having a hard time figuring out what my problem might be.

I set the format for the Vector Layer to GeoJSON. My code for the layer is below:

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Filtered by Zoom Level", {
                        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), 
                                    refresh,
                                    ],

                        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                            url: "http://server:8080/test-webapp/servlet",
                        }),

                        filter: filter,

                        styleMap: styleMap,
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                            externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                            internalProject: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
                        })

                    });
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what the issue might be?

Thanks,

-Rob

Comment: To look a bit deeper into what OL sees, you could try pointing to OpenLayers.debug.js instead of OpenLayers.js. They are both at the top level of the OL directory.

Comment: Have you looked at your traffic?  Is the request to the server failing?

Comment: Thanks katahdin, I will take a look at that. Jamie, the request to the server appears to be working. In Firebug, the Response for the GET request is correct.

Comment: Any chance to see the geoJSON ?  And do give us your openlayers versions please.

Comment: The geoJSON response looks like this:

{"features":[{"type":"Point","coordinates":[15.8,4.1]}],"type":"FeatureCollection"}

It is possible that I am not adhering to the geoJSON standards. I am using OpenLayers version 2.12.

Thanks.

Comment: After taking another look at the geoJSON standards, it looks like I was doing this incorrectly. The geoJSON now looks like:

{"features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[15.8,4.1]}}],"type":"FeatureCollection"}

However, that change did not solve the problem I was experiencing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I also needed to add a format field to the protocol object, not just in the layer object. The working code is:

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Filtered by Zoom Level", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), 
                                refresh,
                                ],

                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "http://server:8080/test-webapp/servlet",
                        format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                            externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                            internalProject: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
                        })
                    }),

                    filter: filter,

                    styleMap: styleMap,
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                        externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                        internalProject: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
                    })

                });
```

Thank you to everybody for the suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

I edited a GeoJSON map of my own to match your loading strategy. The map also failed to load for me. I got rid of the "refresh" command and the map loaded as normal. I'd try that.

So:

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Filtered by Zoom Level", {
                    strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],

                    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                        url: "http://server:8080/test-webapp/servlet",
                    }),

                    filter: filter,

                    styleMap: styleMap,
                    format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                        externalProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                        internalProject: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913")
                    })

                });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion bshender. Unfortunately, removing the refresh strategy did not fix the problem. I didn't include the code for the strategy, but I have used it successfully in another situation.